# Inconsistency when getting class attribute of different R objects using C function

Tags: c, r, syntax, internals

I wrote a simple C function to use with `inline` in R which *should* take any object and return that objects class. I have tried to follow the [**Writing R Extensions**](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Classes) manual, which states

> The `getAttrib` and `setAttrib` functions get and set individual attributes. Their second argument is a `SEXP` defining the name in the symbol table of the attribute we want; these and many such symbols are defined in the header file `Rinternals.h`.

In addition it also states..

> In R the `class` is just the attribute named `"class"` so it can be handled as such.

So I wrote this...

```
#  required package
require( inline )

#  Simple C function to get "class" attribute of an R object
classC <- cfunction( c(x = "ANY") , '

  SEXP out;
  PROTECT(out = allocVector(STRSXP, 1));
  SET_STRING_ELT(out, 0, mkChar("class"));
  UNPROTECT(1);
  return  getAttrib(x, out) ;

')
```

But testing it on various different classes of R object sometimes return the `class`, but usually returns `NULL`. I don't see the connection between the object types it *does* work on, so not sure where I have gone wrong...

```
#  Various classes of objects
con <- file("text.txt")
d <- data.frame( a = 1 )
e <- new.env()
f <- y ~ 1
fun <- function(x) x^2
i <- 1L:10L
l <- list( 1 , 2 , 3 )
m <- matrix( 1 , 10 , 10 )
n <- runif(1)
v <- 1:10
```

And running the function I get...

```
#  Output from the function
classC(con)
#[1] "file"       "connection"
classC(d)
#[1] "data.frame"
classC(e)
#NULL
classC(f)
#[1] "formula"
classC(fun)
NULL
classC(i)
NULL
classC(l)
#NULL
classC(m)
#NULL
classC(n)
#NULL
classC(v)
#NULL
```

What am I missing? I am interested because I eventually I would like to write a little helper function that returns a vector of all object names in the `globalenvironment` that are of a particular `class`. But mainly it's for my own curiosity and learning, I am aware that I *could* do something like:

```
sapply( ls() , function(x) class( get( x ) ) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation lies :) What you did is equivalent to the R function:

```
classR = function(x) attributes(x)$class
```

What R does when you call `class` is this:

```
SEXP R_data_class(SEXP obj, Rboolean singleString)
{
    SEXP value, klass = getAttrib(obj, R_ClassSymbol);
    int n = length(klass);
    if(n == 1 || (n > 0 && !singleString))
        return(klass);
    if(n == 0) {
        SEXP dim = getAttrib(obj, R_DimSymbol);
        int nd = length(dim);
        if(nd > 0) {
            if(nd == 2)
                klass = mkChar("matrix");
            else
                klass = mkChar("array");
        }
        else {
          SEXPTYPE t = TYPEOF(obj);
          switch(t) {
          case CLOSXP: case SPECIALSXP: case BUILTINSXP:
            klass = mkChar("function");
            break;
          case REALSXP:
            klass = mkChar("numeric");
            break;
          case SYMSXP:
            klass = mkChar("name");
            break;
          case LANGSXP:
            klass = lang2str(obj, t);
            break;
          default:
            klass = type2str(t);
          }
        }
    }
    else
        klass = asChar(klass);
    PROTECT(klass);
    value = ScalarString(klass);
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return value;
}
```

So you can see that it does a bunch of checks for all those cases where you got `NULL`.

An easy option for you is to just call `class` from your function:

```
eval(lang2(install("class"), x), R_GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the function that gets used for S3 objects? It looked to me like `R_do_data_class` gets used for those. `R_data_class` is preceded by a note that seems (to me) to indicate that it gets used for S4 classes.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien oh, I have no idea. I think this is a good starting point for me to do some more research, but I'll un-accept for now (sorry eddi!) as it seems my original question *could* be unanswered, so don't want people to ignore it.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien `R_do_data_class` calls either this or `R_data_class2`. I don't think it matters a lot which you look at, as it's for illustration purposes only as the idea is the same in both functions.